# Using Apache Spark as a backend for web application

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

We have Terabytes of data stored in HDFS, comprising of customer data and behavioral information. Business Analysts want to perform slicing and dicing of this data using filters.

These filters are similar to Spark RDD filters. Some examples of the filter are:
`age > 18 and age < 35`, `date between 10-02-2015, 20-02-2015`, `gender=male`, `country in (UK, US, India)`, etc. We want to integrate this filter functionality in our JSF (or Play) based web application.

Analysts would like to experiment by applying/removing filters, and verifying if the count of the final filtered data is as desired. This is a repeated exercise, and the maximum number of people using this web application could be around 100.

We are planning to use Scala as a programming language for implementing the filters. The web application would initialize a single SparkContext at the load of the server, and every filter would reuse the same SparkContext.

Is Spark good for this use case of interactive querying through a web application. Also, the idea of sharing a single SparkContext, is this a work-around approach? The other alternative we have is Apache Hive with Tez engine using ORC compressed file format, and querying using JDBC/Thrift. Is this option better than Spark, for the given job?

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Don't post text as a long letter no body will read it. Split it into important sections so it's clear and easily readable what you are asking about.

Comment: Thanks Mikel, It was my first post.

Answer (score 4):

It's not the best use case for Spark, but it is completely possible. The latency can be high though.

You might want to check out [Spark Jobserver](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver), it should offer most of your required features. You can also get an SQL view over your data using Spark's JDBC Thrift server.

In general I'd advise using SparkSQL for this, it already handles a lot of the things you might be interested in.

Another option would be to use [Databricks Cloud](https://databricks.com/product/databricks-cloud), but it's not publicly available yet.

Answer (score 3):

> Analysts would like to experiment by applying/removing filters, and verifying if the count of the final filtered data is as desired. This is a repeated exercise, and the maximum number of people using this web application could be around 100.

[Apache Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/) provides a framework for interactively ingesting and visualizing data (via web application) using apache spark as the back end. Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_PQbVH_aO5E&feature=youtu.be) demonstrating the features.

> Also, the idea of sharing a single SparkContext, is this a work-around approach?

It looks like that project uses a single sparkContext for low latency query jobs.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to know which solution you chose in the end.

I have two propositions:

1. following the zeppelin idea of @quickinsights, there is also the interactive notebook [jupyter](http://jupyter.org) that is well established now. It is firstly designed for python, but specialized *kernel* can be installed. I tried using [toree](https://github.com/apache/incubator-toree/blob/master/README.md) a couple of month ago. The basic installation is simple:

   `pip install jupyter`

   `pip install toree`

   `jupyter install toree`

   but at the time I had to do a
   couple low level twicks to make it works (s.as editing `/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/toree/kernel.json`). But it worked and I could use a spark cluster from a scala notebook. [Check this tuto, it
   fits what I have in
   memory](http://technippet.blogspot.fr/2016/02/running-apache-spark-in-jupyter-notebook.html).
2. Most (all?) docs on spark speak about running app with spark-submit or using spark-shell for interactive usage (sorry but spark&scala shell are so disappointing...). They never speak about using spark in an interactive app, such as a web-app. It is possible (I tried), but there are indeed some issues to be check, such as sharing sparkContext as you mentioned, and also some issues about managing dependencies. You can checks the [two getting-started-prototypes](http://julien.diener.website/?p=136) I made to use spark in a spring web-app. It is in java, but I would strongly recommend using scala. I did not work long enough with this to learn a lot. However I can say that it is possible, and it works well (tried on a 12 nodes cluster + app running on an edge node)

   Just remember that the spark driver, i.e. where the code with rdd is running, should be physically on the same cluster that the spark nodes: there are lots of communications between the driver and the workers.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Livy](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/) enables programmatic, fault-tolerant, multi-tenant submission of Spark jobs from web/mobile apps (no Spark client needed). So, multiple users can interact with your Spark cluster concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem at our company. We have ~2-2.5 TB of data in the form of logs. Had some basic analytics to do on that data.

We used following:

- Apache Flink for Streaming data from source to HDFS via Hive.
- Have Zeppelin configured on the top of HDFS.
- SQL interface for Joins and JDBC connection to connect to HDFS via
  hive.
- Spark for putting batches of data offline

**You can use Flink + Hive-HDFS**

> Filters can be applied via SQL ( Yes! everything is supported in latest releases)
>
> Zeppelin can automate task of report generation and it has cool features of filters without actually mordifying sql queries using ${sql-variable} feature.

Check it out. I am sure you'll find your answer:)

Thanks.